# Laravel 8 bootstrap auth error message not displayed

Tags: laravel, validation, laravel-blade

I installed a new laravel 8 with bootstrap auth.

I added first_name and last_name to the users table and to the register controller validation, blade etc.

My form:

```
 <form method="POST" action="{{ route('register') }}">
    @csrf

    <div class="form-group row">
       <label for="first_name" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">First Name</label>

    <div class="col-md-6">
      <input id="first_name" type="text" class="form-control @error('first_name') is-invalid @enderror" name="first_name" value="{{ old('first_name') }}" required autocomplete="first_name" autofocus>

   @error('first_name')
       <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
         <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
       </span>
   @enderror
 </div>
 </div>.... and the rest of the fields
```

I try to register a user without filling any of the fields.

The fields get a red border and the first field (first_name) get a tooltip with the message please fill out this field.

But I don't see the error messages that should appaer under each field:

```
@error('first_name')
   <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
      <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
   </span>
@enderror
```

This does not show anything.

I don't want tooltips I want the messages to appear under the fields.

How do I do that? why does it ignore the @error statement in the blade file?

Also I don't see where it goes in the dev console, when I click submit I don't see anything in the console.

What is going on here?

Comment: Is the form definitely getting submitted? I only ask because what you've described sounds like browser validation rather than server side validation. Do you have `required` on the input element?

Comment: Hi @Rwd, thank you for replying. The inputs do not have required on them. It is the form that was created by laravel auth ui I did not change anything but change the name field to first_name and added a last_name field. I also don't see any javascript on the file so I really don't understand where and how is it submitted if at all

Comment: Looking at the code for your form that updated your question with, there is a `required` attribute on the input. This is causing the browser validation to fail when you try to submit without a value, therefore stopping the form from being submitted. If you do not want browser validation for this form then remove the `required` attributes from the `<input />` elements.

Comment: Oh dear, I don't know how I missed that.... I guess my eyes are not what they used to be... ;) Thank you so much.

Comment: Not to worry. It happens to all of us! ;)